# Null Pointer Exception on finishing Activity in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

I have an Activity which has two different layouts based on grid view and full page gallery view, when user clicks on an image in grid view it goes to full screen gallery. When the user in full screen Gallery and when back button is clicked it goes back to grid view. Finally if the user again clicks back button once more I want Activity to terminates.

Here is How I handle switching views on back button pressed, It works well except finishing activity. I have null pointer exception on the line I call finish(). How can I handle it?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gallery_view);

    if(mPager.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

        setContentView(R.layout.thumbnail_gallery);
        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        g.setAdapter(new GridGallery(this));

        return;

    }else {
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the solutions to accept given answers for my questions. If I just accept all the answers or one of the answers even it is not the exact solution I may guide the people to the wrong way and waste their time. If you look at my profile you will see that most of the answers are even not related with the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I think logcat can help figure out a problem

Comment: try calling `super.onBackPressed();` instead of `finish();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment I found the answer. I have seen this issue in somewhere else in stackoverflow. If you vote up the question It may help the others.

Comment: @Vladimir I have also tried that way, it also works quite well. But the issue was the method findViewById(). I guess when we call them it requires setContentView or something otherwise it causes Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: If you found the solution, post it as answer and accept it =)

Comment: Yeah I tried it :) but because of my reputation stackoverflow does not let me to do this :)

Comment: Instead I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the reason of `NullPointerException` in the end. The method `findViewById` causes it. Instead of checking the visibility of the layout, I have used a boolean variable to check it. Basically when I set the the content view to a layout I assign this variable to true, and then when I switch the view I also switch the boolean variable to false. It works quite well.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(isGalleryVisible) {

        setContentView(R.layout.thumbnail_gallery);
        GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
        g.setAdapter(new GridGallery(this));
        isGalleryVisible = false;
        return;
    } else {
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

And in the place I switch the view I assign it to true. Take a look below.

```
GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
g.setAdapter(new GridGallery(context));
isGalleryVisible = false;
g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(context);
     pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gallery_view);
     pager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);
     pager.setCurrentItem(position);
     isGalleryVisible = true;
  }
});
```